# What does "poddisruptionbudgets.policy "zk-pdb" already exists" mean while installing with helm?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-zookeeper, kubernetes-helm, dremio

I've been following this tutorial for setting up dremio with k8s: https://www.dremio.com/tutorials/python-dremio-and-kubernetes/

when attempting to install using charts in https://github.com/dremio/dremio-cloud-tools/, I get the following error message:

`Error: release mean-waterbuffalo failed: poddisruptionbudgets.policy "zk-pdb" already exists`

What does this mean and how should one go about resolving it?

Comment: are you getting this while installing it first time or you get this if you run the install command second time?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu the second time. It was interrupted the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you use `helm install` to install a chart first time and you want to reinstall it again for some reason then before running the helm install you can clean up the old installation using `helm uninstall`

Alternatively if you intend just to upgrade an existing chart installation with some changes you can use `helm upgrade`

Comment: I am facing the same issue by using `helm upgrade --install` which basically install or upgrade the charts.

Answer (score 1):

Check the PDB using:

```
kubectl get poddisruptionbudgets zk-pdb
```

If found, delete it with:

```
kubectl delete poddisruptionbudgets zk-pdb
```

Comment: unfortunately more errors of the same kind appear:
`configmaps "dremio-config" already exists`